# Cannot add anymore "Time in othe location" since 15.04 update

Tags: 15.04, time

Since the update (ubuntu 14.10 → ubuntu 15.04), I cannot add anymore Time in other locations.

Once I click on "Choose Locations...", the menu appear. I click on "+" but when I write the name of the city nothing happens anymore.

Is there a way to reset everything or to solve this issue?

I do not use any particular ppa and I did a standard update after the release of ubuntu 15.04.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bug in 15.04

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1440157
Why this place needs 30 characters is weird so ...

Comment: I've just added a workaround there: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1440157/comments/10